# Encryption - whole file or single fields?

Tags: android, performance, security, encryption

I have to encrypt a list containing three fields for each record (a tag, a username and a password).

Those will be saved in a JSON structure and then written to storage.

My question is, should I encrypt the whole file or should I encrypt the single fields, convert the encrypted strings to Base64 and put those encrypted fields in the JSON file?

Considering I don't expect the file to become very big (say, less then a MB), that I'll always be reading it as a whole and that the target platform is Android, what is the best approach in terms of performance and security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend encrypting the entire file. If you encrypt field by field, then an attacker will see that the data is an array of (tag, username, password). That already exposes part of your data structure and weakens the encryption. Encrypting and decrypting the entire file might even be faster than doing each field separately, although for the sizes you are talking about I don't think that's an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Encryption is significantly weakened if you're encrypting less than an entire block at once.  So encrypt the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should encrypt the entire file.  However if you are using a poor implementation then this can work against you.   For instance if you use a stream cipher like RC4 and you reuse the key,  then the file structure can be used against you by revealing sections of the prng stream.   This was used in the WEP attack.  But the problem here is the weak implementation.

In short use CBC or CMAC mode with a random IV and Blowfish or AES-256 with an s2k function or random key.  Also keep in mind that there is no place to hide a secret key on the android or iphone without the user being able to access it.